# Ruby on Rails Change/Update Password with Modal on Profile Page Validate Old Password, add New Password, Confirm New Password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, passwords, change-password, twitter-bootstrap-form

I am trying to update the user password on the profile page. To give you context, the user will click a "Change Password" link on their profile page, which will then show a modal with a bootstrap_form_for asking to confirm Old Password, type a New Password, and Confirm New Password.

Currently, I have the method passing successfully, however the password in the database in not being changed. I am not using Devise, this is done from scratch.

Ideally, I want to make sure the Old Password is correctly validated, then the new one updated in the database.

I left some commented out code in the Users Controller so you can see some of what I have been trying.

Please advise! Thank you!

**Routes**

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get :confirm_email
  end
end

get 'change_password' => 'users#change_password'
patch 'change_password' => 'users#change_password'
```

**Users Controller:**

```
def update
  @user = User.find(@current_user)
  User.update(@user, edit_user_params)
  @user.save
  redirect_to user_path
end

def change_password
  @user = User.find(@current_user)
  current_password = params[:user][:current_password]
  user = User.authenticate(@user.email, current_password)
  if @user && user
    # @user.update.password = params[:new_password]
    # new_password = params[:password]
    # @user.update(new_password)
    User.update(@user, change_password_params)
    @user.save
    flash[:success] = "Password successfully changed!"
    redirect_to user_path(@current_user)
  else
    flash[:danger] = "Your old password was incorrect. Please try again."
    redirect_to user_path(@current_user)
  end
end

private

def user_params
  params.require(:new_user).permit(:name,:email,:password)
end

def edit_user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name,:email,:password,:city,:state_id,:country_id,:about)
end

def change_password_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:password)
end
```

**edit.html.erb (modal portion)**

```
<!-- Change Password Modal -->

<div id="changepasswordmodal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                  <h3 class="">Change Password</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <%= bootstrap_form_for @user, url: change_password_path do |p| %>
              <%= p.password_field :current_password, hide_label: true, placeholder: "Enter your Old Password", class: "input-lg required" %>
              <%= p.password_field :password, hide_label: true, placeholder: "Enter a New Password", class: "input-lg required" %>
              <%= p.password_field :password_confirmation, hide_label: true, placeholder: "Confirm New Password", class: "input-lg required"%>

              <%= p.submit "Change Password", :class=> "btn btn-primary" %>
              <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**User Model (Relevant portion only)**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  before_create :confirmation_token

  belongs_to :state
  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :account_type

  has_many :authentications

  validates :email,
    presence: true,
    uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false},
    format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i, on: :create }

  validates :password,
    presence: true,
    :on => :create


  def self.authenticate email, password
    User.find_by_email(email).try(:authenticate, password)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been wondering for long times to find the problem:

```
def change_password
  @user = User.find(@current_user)
  current_password = params[:user][:current_password]
  user = User.authenticate(@user.email, current_password)
  if @user && user
    # @user.update.password = params[:new_password]
    # new_password = params[:password]
    # @user.update(new_password)
    user.update_attribute(password: params[:user][:current_password])
    flash[:success] = "Password successfully changed!"
    redirect_to user_path(@current_user)
  else
    flash[:danger] = "Your old password was incorrect. Please try again."
    redirect_to user_path(@current_user)
  end
end
```

There are many ways to update data. You can take a look [different way to update attribute](http://www.davidverhasselt.com/set-attributes-in-activerecord/). I would prefer to choose update_attribute because in this case we don't have to validate another field. See how a [update_attribute description](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attribute). You have to remove `@user.save` because update_attribute has already saved it. Hopefully, It can help you.